# Why does Windows Phone 7 emulator uses high CPU on Windows 8 os?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-7-emulator

I installed the Windows Phone 8 SDK on Windows 8. I want to test my Windows Phone 7 application on Windows Phone 7 emulator, which comes from WP8 SDK. The Windows Phone 7 Emulator uses 25 % percent CPU constantly, even if I don't interact with them. 
My machine has Core i5 540m CPU, 8 GB RAM, hyper-V enabled, hyper threading enabled.